# Pagination testing via cypress JS

Tags: node.js, pagination, cypress

[image]I need to test that when I select some model car, as a result, I have only that model in all pages. So basically I do pagination testing. But I do something wrong that it does not moves to another page although selectors are correct. Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
findItem("AUDI")
   });
   async function findItem(value) {
       async function findInPage(index) {
           let found = false;
           cy.get("li.page-item:not(.page-pre):not(.page-next)").as("pages");
           await cy.get("@pages")
               .its("length")
               .then(async (len) => {
                   if (index >= len) {
                       return false;
                   } else {
                       await cy.get("@pages")
                           .eq(index)
                           .click();
                       await cy.get("table tr > td:nth-child(5) p")
                           .each(async ($itemNameEl, index) => {
                               const itemText = $itemNameEl.text().toUpperCase();
                               cy.log('item ', itemText);
                               if (itemText.includes(value)) {
                                   found = true;
                                   await cy.wrap($itemNameEl).eq(index);
                                   //cy.get('.chakra-text.css-0').should('include', value)
                                   cy.get('.css-1b4k5p > .chakra-text.css-0')
                                   .each(($el) => {
                                       expect($el.text().toUpperCase()).to.include(value)
                                    
                                   })
                                   return false;
                               }
                           })
                           .then(() => {
                               if (!found) {
                                   findInPage(++index);
                               }
                           });
                   }
               });
       }
       findInPage(0);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

A simple example without aliases, async functions, etc, just using recursion and a single NEXT PAGE button (that I see you have in your screen shot) would look like this (tested and working on [bootstrap pagination](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/pagination/) examples):

```
it('Some test', () => {
    cy.visit('/')
    const findInPage = () => {
        cy.get('li:has(a.page-link:has(span:contains(»)))').then((el) => {
            // do your test
            if (el.hasClass('disabled')) {
                // on last page, break out
                return
            }
            cy.wrap(el).click()
            findInPage()
        })
    }
    findInPage()
});
```

How this works: Look for `li` element which represents a single pagination next-page button, in bootstrap case it has child `a` tag which has child `span` tag which contains an icon `»`. Once you reach last page, the button get's disabled by adding `.disabled` class to `li` tag which is checked for on every page. Using this it doesn't matter if you have 3 or 33 pages and if some numbers are hidden with `...`

Reference: https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/cypress-recurse/

Comment: Good answer, but I would suggest a check before inner call to `findInPage()` to ensure the next page has finished loading.

Answer (score 0):

```
const nextPageArrow = '[aria-label="next page"]'
  const findInPage = () => {
    cy.get(nextPageArrow).then((el) => {
      if (el.hasClass('disabled')) {
        return
      }
      cy.intercept('POST', '**/v1/getrecords*').as('records')
      cy.wrap(el).click()
      cy.wait('@records')
      findInPage()
    })
  }
  findInPage()
```